# Query syntax error

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get the `GroupID` field of my `ea_appointments` table but this error appear:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as g FROM (`ea_appointments`)' at line 1
>
> SELECT COALESCE(MAX(GroupID), `0)` + 1 as g FROM (`ea_appointments`)
>
> Line Number: 330

Now in my table I've no values inserted yet, the `GroupID` it's needed because I want to get the same id inserting multiple appointments.

For example some like this. [SQL FIDDLE.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/285e1/1)

Now in `CodeIgniter` I've this code:

```
    $this->db->select('COALESCE(MAX(GroupID), 0) + 1 as g')->from('ea_appointments');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $groupId = $query->g;

    $appointment['GroupID'] = $groupId;

    if(!$this->db->insert('ea_appointments', $appointment))
    {
        throw new Exception('Error.');
    }

    $insert_id = intval($this->db->insert_id());
```

But seems not working, and I don't know why.

NB: This code is called recursively by a foreach, in this foreach is passed as parameter the variable `$appointment`, this contain each time different services associated for the same appointment.

**NEW CODE**

```
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COALESCE(MAX(GroupID), 0) +1 AS g FROM ea_appointments");

    $appointment['GroupID'] = $query;

    if(!$this->db->insert('ea_appointments', $appointment))
    {
        throw new Exception('Appuntamento non inserito.');
    }
```

This query working but when I perform the `insert()` I get this error:

> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string
>
> Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 552
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
>
> INSERT INTO `ea_appointments` (`id_users_provider`, `start_datetime`, `end_datetime`, `notes`, `is_unavailable`, `id_users_customer`, `id_services`, `book_datetime`, `hash`, `GroupID`) VALUES ('85', '2015-11-15 12:15:00', '2015-11-15 12:15:00', '', 0, '87', '13', '2015-11-15 03:12:48', '345831a567cdf7c5f71a3a5a12121f2d', )

Comment: try breaking the query once.

Comment: `$this->db->from('ea_appointments')`

Comment: Okay with only this: $this->db->select('COALESCE(MAX(GroupID), 0) + 1 as g')->from('ea_appointments'); the ajax calling return SUCCESS, so this line not cause any problems. Maybe is the ->get()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually replace your query like this,

```
$this->db->select('COALESCE(MAX(GroupID), 0) + 1 as g');
$query = $this->db->get('ea_appointments');
```

**EDIT**

```
$this->db->query("SELECT COALESCE(MAX(GroupID), 0) +1 AS g FROM ea_appointments");
```

Comment: Same error: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as g FROM (`ea_appointments`)' at line 1

SELECT COALESCE(MAX(GroupID), `0)` + 1 as g FROM (`ea_appointments`)

Comment: This shud be `$groupId = $query->row()->g;`

Comment: Okay now there is no error. But my GroupId increment to each insert, I want use GroupId for have the same id of my appointment as the Fiddle example. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: according to your code, you have written login that your groupId incremenrs everytime..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95168/discussion-between-dillinger-and-niranjan-n-raju).